# How to calculate/determine how much percentage/portion of a circle a given shape is (most likely a partial circle)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-registration

Problem i am trying to tackle is very simple, however, i am stuck on thinking how to do that. I have extracted masks using segmentation algorithms for pipe visible openings (not all the openings are clear, most results in partial circles). I want to determine how much percentage the mask is of overall pipe opening.

I am looking for some generic solution since images i am dealing with are of different scales and sizes. An idea i have in mind is to somehow fit the given mask in the circular shape (draw circle from given partial circular shape), however, unable to find any support.

Any idea, how i can tackle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Image 1 is the ideal image where the openings are clear. I can extract the masks as separate and want to determine how much part the mask is of the circle. In this case ideally it should say 100% which means all clear.

Image 2 on the other hand is the partial blocked opening. This is where i want to fit those masks as circle and determine how much part of circle that part is, in this case less than 50%, which means 50% blocked. Hope it clears the situation

[An Ideal image with Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm1nA.jpg)

[Image with partial masks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7flZH.jpg)

Comment: Sample images please.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for comment. I have added more details with images. Hope it helps you to understand the problem better.

Comment: This looks like an uneasy task. When you have the outlines of the regions, you can use an ellipse fitting algorithm. But it must be able to find the ellipse despite alien parts of the outline. (Typical research paper: "A Fast and Robust Ellipse-Detection Method Based on Sorted Merging".) After the ellipse is fitted, you can estimate the fraction of the outline that matches the ellipse. This gives you an approximation of the fraction of the area.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for suggestion. I will look into it.